# Adjusting Button Visiblity with MouseOver

Tags: wpf, button, visibility

I want to display a button only when the user puts the mouse over its location, once the mouse leaves the area, the button should go back to being Hidden.  Here is my code for the buttons.

```
<StackPanel Name="ButtonOptions" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="DarkBlue" Height="50" Width="auto">
    <!--<StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>-->
    <Button Name="LoginButton" FontSize="12" Click="LoginButton_Click" Content="Log In" Width="100" Height="31" Margin="50,0,0,0" 
            FontFamily="Arial" Visibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True" MouseEnter="LoginButton_MouseEnter" />
    <Button Name="OptionsButton" Content="Options" Width="100" Height="31" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontFamily="Arial"
            FontSize="12" Click="OptionsButton_Click" Visibility="Hidden" IsEnabled="False"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The resouces section is commented out because I tried that and it wasn't working.  My log in button has the the following eventhandler attached..

```
LoginButton.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(LoginButton_MouseEnter);
```

The method that handles this is..

```
private void LoginButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Made in the login button listener for mouseOver");

    LoginButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

When I run my app, nothing happens when I put over the location where the button should be.  However, if I set the log in button's visibility to be Visible initially, I can see the button, and when I click on it, my log in logic method for a users sign in is overridden, and I am prompted with the message box in the MouseEventListener method for "Made in the login button listener for mouseOver".  Not only that, but I receive two of these messages (as soon as I click "Ok" the first time, it immediately pops up again)  I am not sure why it doesn't work, nor why my click event method is ignored and NOW the mouseEvent method occurs.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Events don't fire when a button is hidden or collapsed.

Comment: Don't use pop-ups to diagnose mouse overs. You are getting two pop-ups because when you mouse over the dialog to close it, you are no longer moused over the element that triggered it! When the dialog closes, it'll fire the mouse over event again.

Comment: @iterationx: I think that's true, but you *might* be able to override it if you get IsHitTestVisible.

Comment: Like mentioned above Visibiliy.Hidden might cause the button to stop receiving mouse events.  The MSDN documentation on Visibility does not mention this though.  If nothing else works try toggling the Opacity Property instead of Visibility and see if that helps.

Comment: @BojinLi: I was just about to suggest using opacity as well. I'm pretty sure you'll still get mouse events when opacity is set to 0. Also, as a bonus, you could think about animating the opacity when you mouse over so that you button fades in instead of popping in. All this, of course, is ignoring whether or not having hidden elements is a good idea in the first place!

Comment: @MattBurland - I think the reason why I was getting two popUps was because I defined in the mouseEvent in the XAML and in the code behind.  I deleted the "LoginButton.MouseEnter += ...." line and the same behavior occurs, but I only get one pop up dialog. Your animation ideal sounds pretty cool, although I have just started learning WPF (obviously) and have no idea how to animate anything yet.

Comment: @Bojin Li (and kinda MattBurland) - The OPACITY adjustment works, thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Off-topic:
First of all, having items suddenly appear "under" your mouse is really a bad design and I would advise on changing it.

On-topic:
As others already mentioned in the comments section, whenever a control is Hidden or Collapsed it will stop processing any inputs, so you won't trigger any triggers.

You could use the Opacity property to implement the behavior you seek and furthermore use EventTriggers on "MouseEnter" and "MouseLeave" to be able to put a nice animation there. Here's how I would write that style:

```
<Style x:Key="FadeOutButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard >
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard >
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now, back on my first idea, I would strongly suggest to keep the button visible even when mouse is not over (opacity = 0.2 in my example above) and play with the animation times. If it's not an option, you can always set the animation durations to 0:0:0 and opacity value ti 0 and you will get the same result as the Visibility (at least visually).

Later Edit: 
You must apply the style on your buttons like this:

```
<Button Content="my button" Style="{StaticResource FadeOutButton}" Opacity="0.2"/>
```

Comment: +1 for the comment about the wisdom (or lack thereof) of hidden elements.

Comment: @Matt Burland and AlexDrenea - I realize its not the best way to do something, but this app is going on a tv that will display data from a database, managers can come in and adjust what is displayed on the screen through other windows, opened by the buttons.  They are hidden because it would be ugly to show these buttons on the tv's , and managers would know about their location when using the app.

Comment: @AlexDrenea - I tried to add your code at the top of my xaml as a window resource, but nothing happened.  Do I need to include the resource where I define my button, or is the style universal to all buttons in the window?  Or could my MouseEnter and MouseLeave events just be overriding this style?

Comment: You don't want the style to be applied to all the buttons in the application so the style is not automatically applied to all buttons (remove the x:Key part if you want that). See my edited post for the usage.

Comment: I find the comments about the "wisdom" of hidden screen elements to be condescending. There could be a completely valid reason for having a hidden controls in the user interface. The OP did not describe his project in sufficient detail for you to make this judgement.

Comment: Wow thanks!  I notice that the first time I put my mouse over the buttons that the animation does not seem to happen, I see the buttons instantaneously.  However for every other time I move my mouse over buttons, the animation is present. Weird.

Comment: You should configure your button's Opacity to the value you have in the "To" parameter of the MouseLeave event when you define it in XAML. That't why it does not work the first time. I will update the post.

Comment: Valid reason for hidden elements: an image pan/zoom control in which the pan/zoom buttons stay hidden unless the mouse is within the control.

Comment: @PIntag: it is only condescending if you blow things wildly out of proportion.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: perhaps "condescending" is too strong of a word for this situation, but I stand by my point. I mean, really, can any one person know everything about all possible UIs that they can proclaim it "bad design"?